# Calculating Tree Vertices

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Can someone review my logic on this? I'm not sure I'm right and as its a review I want to understand it. The question is are there graphs with v vertices and v-1 edges and no cycles that are not trees?  Give a proof or a counterexample.

Had issues pasting it in question so will add what I have below in comment:

Comment: What I have is somewhat proved via induction, thus taking the defined as the base s(z) statement, with n vertices and n-1 edges. And proving sA as a 1vertex 0 edge tree, then sB as a 2vertex 1 edge tree, then the statement must be true because of s(k) where its the amount of vertices in the given?

Comment: The answer is that there are such graphs (but not if you further assumed the graph was connected...)

Comment: So if what I have is wrong for the proof how would you show that its true?

Comment: Find a counterexample! I gave you a hint...

Comment: So if I assume its not connected though, isn't that proving that there are cycles on the vertices though?

Comment: Doh I misread, you were right (but I don't understand your proposed induction proof)

Comment: Anyways, if the graph has no cycles then it's at least a forest. So if you have a forest with $k$ components, how many edges does it have?

Answer (score 0):

You’re almost correct in thinking that a simple graph with $n$ vertices and $n-1$ edges is a tree, and induction is the natural way to try to prove it, but the statement isn’t quite true, and I’m afraid that I can’t make any sense of the induction step of your attempted proof. One way to see why it’s not quite true, and what additional hypothesis is needed in order to make it true, is to attempt to carry out the proof.

Let $P(n)$ be the statement that a simple graph with $n$ vertices and $n-1$ edges is a tree. Since there is only one graph with one vertex and no edges, and it’s a tree, $P(1)$ is true; that much you’d already done.

For the induction step you want to assume that $P(n)$ is true and try to prove $P(n+1)$. Suppose, then, that $P(n)$ is true, and that $G$ is a simple graph with $n+1$ vertices and $(n+1)-1=n$ edges; we want to show that $G$ is a tree.

- Suppose that $G$ has a vertex $v$ of degree $1$. Let $G'$ be the graph that remains after $v$ and the one edge incident at $v$ are removed from $G$. Clearly $G'$ has $n$ vertices and $n-1$ edges, so by the induction hypothesis $G'$ is a tree. Now use this to show that $G$ is also a tree.

If $G$ has no vertex of degree $1$, there are two possibilities.

- Suppose that every vertex of $G$ has degree at least $2$. Then the sum of the degrees of the vertices of $G$ is at least $2(n+1)$. But the sum of the degrees of the vertices of a graph is twice the number of edges, so $G$ must have at least $n+1$ edges, contradicting the hypothesis that $G$ has $n$ edges. This case is therefore impossible.

If these were the only two cases to be considered, we’d have proved the theorem at this point. However, we did not require $G$ to be connected, so there is another possibility.

- Suppose that $G$ has a vertex of degree $0$. Let $G'$ be the graph that remains when this vertex is removed. Then $G'$ has $n$ vertices and $n$ edges (and therefore cannot be a tree). Can you find such an example? Once you’ve found one, you’ll have a counterexample to the theorem, though only when we allow $G$ to be disconnected.

Comment: Would the anonymous downvoter care to explain what’s wrong? Or justify the misleading vote?

Comment: +1 Nice Answer. I really do not understand someone has downvoted this. Thanks Brian for your time!